# RecyclerView Adapter in android

Tags: android-recyclerview

In `@override onBindViewHolder` method, I get an error message:

> Non-static field 'mWeatherTextView' cannot be referenced from a
>   static context

I checked for all possible errors but didn't find any, even my code is similar to the solution provided but there is no error showing for the solution provided.

```
package com.example.android.sunshine;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ForecastAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<ForecastAdapter.ForecastAdapterViewHolder> {
private String[] mWeatherData;
public ForecastAdapter(){}
public class ForecastAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
public final TextView mWeatherTextView;
public ForecastAdapterViewHolder(View view){
super(view);
mWeatherTextView =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_weather_data);
    }
}
@Override
public ForecastAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int 
viewType) {
Context context = parent.getContext();
int layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.forecast_list_item;
boolean shouldAttachToParentImmediately = false;
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, 
                       parent,shouldAttachToParentImmediately);
return new ForecastAdapterViewHolder(view);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ForecastAdapterViewHolder holder, int position) 
{
    String weatherForThisDay = mWeatherData[position];
    ForecastAdapterViewHolder.mWeatherTextView.setText(weatherForThisDay);      

    _**/* error message says "Non-static field 'mWeatherTextView' cannot be referenced from a static context" */**_
    }
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(mWeatherData == null) return 0;
    return mWeatherData.length;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `onBindViewHolder`, you will always use the `holder` that has been passed as an argument. So change `ForecastAdapterViewHolder` to `holder` in `setText` line.

```
package com.example.android.sunshine;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ForecastAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<ForecastAdapter.ForecastAdapterViewHolder> {
private String[] mWeatherData;
public ForecastAdapter(){}
public class ForecastAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
public final TextView mWeatherTextView;
public ForecastAdapterViewHolder(View view){
super(view);
mWeatherTextView =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_weather_data);
    }
}
@Override
public ForecastAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int 
viewType) {
Context context = parent.getContext();
int layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.forecast_list_item;
boolean shouldAttachToParentImmediately = false;
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, 
                       parent,shouldAttachToParentImmediately);
return new ForecastAdapterViewHolder(view);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ForecastAdapterViewHolder holder, int position) 
{
    String weatherForThisDay = mWeatherData[position];
    holder.mWeatherTextView.setText(weatherForThisDay);      

    _**/* error message says "Non-static field 'mWeatherTextView' cannot be referenced from a static context" */**_
    }
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(mWeatherData == null) return 0;
    return mWeatherData.length;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ForecastAdapterViewHolder.mWeatherTextView.setText(weatherForThisDay);`

use

```
holder.mWeatherTextView.setText(weatherForThisDay);
```

Comment: Thanku...Your edit solved my problem....:( but stackoverflow allows green tick only for one correct answer...Even if same answer is proposed multiple times...